# jQuery, detect if an element is already toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need with jQuery to know if an element on my page is already toggle or not.

I have a menu with XXX elements.

When i click on an element, i use : `$("#elementXX").slideToggle("slow");` (XX is a number)

If i click on another element, i need to know if an element is already toggle, and i need to close this element before to slideToggle my new element.

How can i do that ? I can't check id by id like #element1, #element2, #element3 etc....

Thanks !

Comment: You can always `.slideUp()` the element unconditionally, without needing to test its current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need toggle, `slideUp` and `slideDown` are a much better fit for your scenario. You can simply do:

```
$("#clickedItem").click(function () {
    var wasVisible = $("#elementXX").is(":visible");
    $("[id^=element]:visible").stop().slideUp("slow");
    if (!wasVisible) {
        $("#elementXX").slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: You probably need `.stop().slideUp()`, in case the element is caught mid animation from a previous event.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Good shout, added :)

Comment: Yeah, but with this solution, i can't close my element when i reclick

Answer (score 4):

You can set the data attributes to some value to know if it is toggled. You can add the attributes in html or use script straightaway to add.

```
$("#elementXX").data("toggled", "true");
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a data-toggled attribute to the element, for searchability.

Answer (score 3):

According to jQuery official website FAQ:

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function () {
   if ($("#elementXX").is(":visible")) {
      // toggled down
   }
   if ($("#elementXX").is(":hidden")) {
      // toggled up
   }
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/